# Coluna não flutuando ao lado

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso que as colunas flutuem uma ao lado da outra dentro de um card. Para isso defini a primeira coluna para ocupar 8 espaços e a segunda 4.

```
col-8 e col-4
```

**Porém elas não estão flutuando uma ao lado da outra.**

Preciso do seguinte comportamento.
[image: Como esta]

Porém mesmo a primeira sendo `col-8` e a segunda `col-4` ela não flutua ao lado, já tentei diminuir os valores e mesmo assim sem sucesso. O único css externo que estou aplicando é em relação as fontes.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="cards text-nowrap">
        <div class="col-8">
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
          <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
          <p>23/04/2019 - 23/04/2022</p><br>
          <button class="btn-danger mt-3">danger</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="circle">
            <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está funcionando pq uma `COL` deve ser filha de uma `ROW`

> In a `grid` layout, content must be placed within `columns` and only `columns` may be immediate children of `rows`.

PORTUGUÊS:
*"Em um layout do `grid`, o conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro de `columns` e somente `columns` podem ser filhos imediatos de `rows`."*

Toda `COL` deve ser filha de uma `ROW`, então basta colocar um `ROW` por fora das `COL` que seu grid vai funcionar como o esperado.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" />


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="cards text-nowrap">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
              <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
              <p>23/04/2019 - 23/04/2022</p><br>
              <button class="btn-danger mt-3">danger</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <div class="circle">
                <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Dica:** Jovem vc precisa dar uma paradinha de 30 min para estudar o Grid do BS, vai te ajudar muito! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works